# Python divide each string by the total lenght of string

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return, jupyter-notebook

Thank you for your help and patience.

I am new to python and am attempting to calculate the number of times a particular atomic symbol appears divided by the total number of atoms. So that the function accepts a list of strings as argument and returns a list containing the fraction of 'C', 'H', 'O' and 'N'. But I keep on getting one result instead of getting all for each of my atoms. My attempt is below:

```
Atoms = ['N', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'O', 'H']

def count_atoms (atoms):
    for a in atoms:
        total = atoms.count(a)/len(atoms)
        return total
```

Then

```
faa = count_atoms(atoms)
print(faa)
```

However I only get one result which is 0.07692307692307693. I was supposed to get a list starting with [0.23076923076923078,..etc], but I don't know how to. I was supposed to calculate the fraction of 'C', 'H', 'O' and 'N' atomic symbols in the molecule using a for loop and a return statement. :( Please help, it will be appreciated.

Comment: As soon as you `return` in a function, the function exits. This means that it only goes through your loop one time. Try `append()`ing your values to a list then returning the whole list outside the loop

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you return the variable total at your first loop. Why don't you use a list to store your values? Like this:

```
atoms = ['N', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'O', 'H'] #python is case sensitive!

def count_atoms (atoms):
    return_list = [] #empty list
    for a in atoms:
        total = atoms.count(a)/len(atoms)
        return_list.append(total) #we add a new item
    return return_list #we return everything and leave the function
```

Comment: Also please note: python is case sensitive. So please use atoms not Atoms.

Comment: No problem, just mark the question as answered so everybody knows your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

@ganderson comment explains the problem. as to alternative implementation here is one using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

atoms = ['N', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'O', 'H']

def count_atoms(atoms):
    num = len(atoms)
    return {atom:count/num for atom, count in Counter(atoms).items()}

print(count_atoms(atoms))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to return a dictionary so you know which element the fraction corresponds to:

```
>>> fractions = {element: Atoms.count(element)/len(Atoms) for element in Atoms}
>>> fractions
{'N': 0.07692307692307693, 'C': 0.23076923076923078, 'O': 0.15384615384615385, 'H': 0.5384615384615384}
```

You can, then, even lookup the fraction for a particular element like:

```
>>> fractions['N']
0.07692307692307693
```

However, if you must use a `for` loop and a return statement, then answer from @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 would be the right one.

Comment: If you're going to go that route, might as well do it on the `set` of Atoms to not needlessly iterate multiple times on each: `{element: Atoms.count(element)/len(Atoms) for element in set(Atoms)}`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner should do

```
[atoms.count(a)/float(len(atoms)) for a in set(atoms)]
```

Or better create a dictionary using comprehension

```
{a:atoms.count(a)/float(len(atoms)) for a in set(atoms)}
```

**Output**

```
{'C': 0.23076923076923078,
 'H': 0.5384615384615384,
 'N': 0.07692307692307693,
 'O': 0.15384615384615385}
```

If you still want to use the for loop. I would suggest to go for `map` which would be a lot cleaner

```
atoms = ['N', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'O', 'H'] 

def count_atoms (a):
    total = atoms.count(a)/float(len(atoms))
    return total

map(count_atoms,atoms)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer